# Python -Initializing Dictionary inside dictionary (if it doesnt exist)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the code below that I am attempting to create a dictionary for each seller_id, store one auth_token for each seller and then store a list of skus.   My issues are:

1 - This code re-inits the seller_id record on each pass.  I am not sure how to turn this in to `create the record for this seller only if it doesnt exist`

```
self.prices_to_request.update({(seller_id): {}})
```

2 - Is `self.prices_to_request[seller_id].setdefault('sku', []).append(sku)`  a better replacement then my `try` statement?  It seems to work but I cant totally test it due to the fact tha the code re-inits the `seller_id` on each pass

Code

```
def add(self, seller_id, auth_token, sku):

    self.prices_to_request.update({(seller_id): {}})
    self.prices_to_request[seller_id]['auth_token'] = auth_token

    try:
      self.prices_to_request[seller_id]['sku'].append(sku)
    except KeyError:
        self.prices_to_request[seller_id]['sku'] = []
        self.prices_to_request[seller_id]['sku'].append(sku)
```

Comment: use `defaultdict(dict)` ?

Comment: The `keys()` function on dictionaries returns a list of all the keys in the dictionary. Just check if the key is in that list, if not add it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setdefault` is what you want. The doc says:

> ```
> setdefault(key[, default])
> ```
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

You should use:

```
self.prices_to_request.setdefault(seller_id, {})['auth_token'] = auth_token
self.prices_to_request[seller_id].setdefault('sku', []).append(sku)
```